# How to export QGIS map into an interactive map?

Tags: qgis, export, qgis2web, mmqgis, online-viewer

I am using the QGIS 2.18.14 and tried 2 ways to export the QGIS map into an interactive map but failed.

1. Export the map to a KML format using the MMQGIS Plugin. I thought I can then import this into the Google Map. As the file is too big to directly import to the Google Map. I uploaded to the Google Drive. However, I still could not import the file and received this message *An error occurred. You may continue to use the application but any change you make may be lost*.
2. Export the map using the QGIS2Web Plugin. However, even I do not move any of the sub-folder, when I open the index.html, the file is empty.

Any advice how to deal with the above situations?

Or any other way to export the QGIS map into an interactive map?

Comment: #2 should be working...

Comment: I hope so... I tried to export several times but still blank. Here is the screenshot (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ELof-DPFSMyR-B49NZaPHZcGg1TXJaRZ/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: qgis2web has had some recent updates https://github.com/tomchadwin/qgis2web

Comment: try just c:/temp for your map output

Comment: If qgis2web fails for you, it's probably best to open an issue at https://github.com/tomchadwin/qgis2web/issues. The new issue template there tells you how to get more debugging information from your browser (F12 > Console).

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] where you will see that there should be only one question asked per question under our focussed Q&A format.

Comment: Thank you. I still cannot figure out why. But I can export by deleting some of the fields. Perhaps there is a limit to the number of the field?

Answer (score 0):

Try [nextgis.com](http://nextgis.com/) + [NextGIS connect plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/nextgis_connect/). But the nextgis.com QGIS rendering is still based on QGIS 2.14 and new styles introduced in 2.18 may be not supported.

Short tutorial in [documentation](http://docs.nextgis.com/docs_ngcom/source/ngqgis_connect.html).

[image]